# Play/Forward video in 2x 3x 4x speed - iPhone SDK

Tags: iphone, ios, mpmovieplayercontroller

I want to play/forward video in MPMoviePlayerController with different speeds. Can any one suggest me how i do this.

Right now i am doing fast forward (On single speed) but in few seconds it come back on normal speed.

Please suggest.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
MPMoviePlayerController Conforms to MPMediaPlayback protocol 
you can see the property currentPlaybackRate as :-
@property(nonatomic) float currentPlaybackRate 
A value of 0 represents that the video is stopped , a value of 1 indicates normal speed and further positive values indicate increased speed while negative ones indicate reverse .
```

Also check your endseeking delegate method of MPMediaPlayback as it is the only method that reverts the playback to normal

Comment: Hai. Thanks for reply. i am doing this. but video playing very slow. i think its only work fine when video is already buffered. please suggest.

Comment: You might want to add the property MPMoviePlayerController.autoPlay according to your needs of application ...according to apple's documentation "This method is called automatically when you call the play method. Calling it before you call play gives the receiver a chance to prepare items sooner and may result in decreased latency when starting playback. However, calling this method may also interrupt any active audio sessions" . Hence it might be helpful in decreasing latency but sometimes net speed also has a role to play in determining the latency.

Comment: for optimizations you can use MPMoviePlayerController.movieSourceType to decrease media recognition delay and/or call [MPMoviePlayerControllerInstance prepareToPlay] when you know that user going to play the video.

Answer (score 0):

**Here is a code to Forward and BackWard Movie as 2x 3x 4x speed for MPMoviePlayerViewController**

**In .h File**

```
@property(nonatomic) float currentPlaybackRate;
```

**In .m File**

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    currentPlaybackRate=1.0; //video Play in Normal speed
}
```

**Now on FastForward and FastBackward Button Action**

```
[fastForward addTarget:self action:@selector(fastForward) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

[fastBackWard addTarget:self action:@selector(fastBackward) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

**Action Code**

```
-(void)fastForward
{
    [mp.moviePlayer pause];
    playPauseButton.selected=TRUE;
    if (currentPlaybackRate < 0.0) {
        currentPlaybackRate = 1.0;
    }

    if (currentPlaybackRate < 4.0) {
        currentPlaybackRate=currentPlaybackRate+1.0;
        NSLog(@"Forward::%f",currentPlaybackRate);
        mp.moviePlayer.currentPlaybackRate=currentPlaybackRate;
    }
}
-(void)fastBackward
{
    [mp.moviePlayer pause];
    playPauseButton.selected=TRUE;

    if (currentPlaybackRate > 0.0) {
        currentPlaybackRate = 0.0;
    }


    if (currentPlaybackRate > -4.0) {
        currentPlaybackRate=currentPlaybackRate-1.0;
        NSLog(@"BackWard::%f",currentPlaybackRate);
        mp.moviePlayer.currentPlaybackRate=currentPlaybackRate;
    }
}
```