# MPMoviePlayerController slow forward and backward motion

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, video, mpmovieplayercontroller

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Play/Forward video in 2x 3x 4x speed - iPhone SDK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10514185/play-forward-video-in-2x-3x-4x-speed-iphone-sdk)

I am currently working on a video based application. I'm using `MPMoviePlayerController` to play the video which i had recorded in my app. My question is what I have to do to play the video in slow forward and backward motion in `MPMoviePlayerController`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
-(IBAction) playSlow:(UIButton *)sender{

    if (frameRate > 1) 
        frameRate -= 0.5;
    else
        frameRate -= 0.25;

    if (frameRate < 0) {
        frameRate=0;
    }

    queuePlayer.rate = frameRate;
}

-(IBAction) playFast:(UIButton *)sender{

    if (frameRate < 1) 
        frameRate += 0.25;
    else
        frameRate += 0.50;

    if(frameRate > 4)
        frameRate = 4;
    queuePlayer.rate = frameRate;
}
```

Comment: it's ok for fast and slow action forward action.. But I need this for backward action too.. If someone having any ideas means please just sharre with me.. It'll be very useful for me.. Thank You..

Comment: In that case,you can set the initial value frame as the total length of the video and in place of incrementing,you can decrement it to 0,hope it works.

Comment: No not like that if we set that rate in negatively, its work good in backward, anyhow thank you dude..

Comment: I added your code, but not work in my project. The log shows 
"live555 demux error: no scale change using old Scale 1.00" this error.

Answer (score 0):

Refer the link [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10514185/play-forward-video-in-2x-3x-4x-speed-iphone-sdk).It may help you.Also the apple documentation [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/mediaplayer/reference/MPMoviePlayerController_Class/Reference/Reference.html) provides you the complete reference about MPMoviePlayerController.